# I see jest.fn(); at the top of a test - what is this for?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

At the top of a test I see I see

```
jest.fn();
```

What is this for?

Having scanned [the documentation](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#content), I thought this function call was for creating mock functions in Jest, but the result is not being assigned, which surprises me.

Comment: Doesn't look like it has any purpose. It could be a leftover of some automated refactoring, where the call was kept for possible side effects even if any usage of its return value was refactored away.

Comment: OK thanks. Sounds plausible. Will accept as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like it has any purpose. It could be a leftover of some automated refactoring, where the call was kept for possible side effects even if any usage of its return value was refactored away.

You could look at the revision history (it *is* stored in version control, right?) if you're curious.

And in any case, if removing it doesn't make the test go red, I would terminate it with extreme prejudice.

Comment: It is in version control!